# How to run the localhost in MAMP without giving any port number?

Tags: php, macos, cakephp, mamp

I am trying to run a `cakephp` project on localhost on `MAMP`, this project run fine on the `WAMP` it has many ajax calls which include path like :

```
   localhost/controllerName/functionName
```

that but in case of `MAMP`

```
 localhost:8888/controllerName/functionName
```

which is not running

any idea how to do this ?

I have the `mod_rewrite` enabled.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believe all you need to do is open up MAMP (not the webstart) and change it to use Ports 80, 443 & 3306 instead of MAMPS ports which one of them is 8888. It should be in the Server section and under the General tab.

I'm using MAMP Pro so not 100% sure if the interface is same for MAMP.

-UPDATE for MAMP

If you open preferences you should see an option for Ports. Then click "set to default Apache and MySql ports". That should allow you to use localhost instead of localhost:8888.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific on how it's not working. Is localhost working after you've changed the Port's from MAMP's default?

Comment: When I give localhost it is not working, When I give localhost:80 redirecting to localhost & not working, only localhost:8888 is working

Comment: You need to restart server after you click on the change ports. Then you should only have to type localhost.

Comment: The method mentioned above will change it to run on port 80 if that's not already in use. Have you tried changing the preferences while the server is turned off and then starting the server up?

Comment: works in my case … there is even a button on the mamp ports tab to set the ports as you suggested

Comment: Stop and start servers didn't work for me, but after set ports to 80, 81... quit Mamp and open again, yes